# Python Guessing Game: Prevent Python guessing the same numbers

Tags: python

I am working on a guessing game in python, i think i have everything only, i want to make the program to guess between numbers it already guessed for example, if the users number is 5, and it picks 3 the user input '+' and it knows the number is higher, and if the program guess 6 the user input '-' and it knows the number is lower than 6, but sometimes it guesses a 2, its obvious that if the number is higher than 3 it can't possibly be 2 right, so how do i write that? I am a beginner at this and i would appreciate if you could make it simple, below is my code.

```
 print("Hello,")
 print("welcome to the guessing game")
 print('I shall guess a number between 1 and 99, and then ask you if am right')
 print('I have a maximum of 20 chances\n')

import random
guess = random.randint(1,99)
print("Your number is %f, Am i right?" % guess)
print('If I am, enter =, If the number is higher enter (+), if the number is lower enter (-)')
ans = input('Which is it: ')
print("You chose %s" % ans)
minguess = 1
maxguess = 99
count = 0

while (count < 20):
    count = count + 1
    if ans == '+':
##I am using these prints to keep track of the numbers and if everything is working correctly
        maxguess1 = guess + 1
        print('THe maxguess is', maxguess1)
        newguess = random.randint(maxguess1, maxguess)
        print('The newguess is', newguess)
        newguess = int(newguess)
        print("Is it %d?" % newguess)
        print('If I am, enter =, If the number is higher enter (+), if the number is lower enter (-)')
        ans = input('Which is it: ')
    elif ans == "-":
        maxguess2 = guess - 1
        print('The minus maxguess is', maxguess2)
        newguess = random.randint(minguess, maxguess2)
        print('The minus newguess is', newguess)
        newguess1 = int(newguess)
        print("Is it %d?" % newguess1)
        print('If I am, enter =, If the number is higher enter (+), if the number is lower enter (-)')
        ans = input('Which is it: ')

    if ans == "=":
        print('YAAAAAAS MAN')
```

### i wanted it to change the numbers whenever it guessed a new number

```
    guess = newguess
```

Comment: Why do you start from a random number? If you know the min and max numbers you could simply half the possible range on each attempt and simply the code.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, it would only run when the user input the '-', plus someone in my class already did it that way, is it wrong to want to have a different approach.

Comment: Not wrong, but that other approach is simpler and guarantees you to have the users number within fewer attempts. Anyway I don't think `maxguess1 = guess + 1` is what you want.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make it work would be appreciated. I am thinking about what you said but am not getting any ideas @Rangad

Comment: You are overwriting `maxguess1` and `maxguess2` on each iteration with the initial value. You don't narrow your range down.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This example is in Python 2.7, NOT Python 3, but the concepts are the same.

Break down the problem into its individual elements:

```
import random

# Possible Range is [1-99], 1 inclusive to 99 inclusive
min_possible = 1
max_possible = 99

# Number of Guesses
max_guesses = 20

# Process
for i in xrange(max_guesses): # Loops through the process 'max_guesses' times

    # Program Takes a Guess
    guess = random.randint(min_possible, max_possible)
    print 'My guess is ' + str(guess)

    # Ask for User Feedback
    user_feedback = ''
    while not user_feedback in ['+', '-', '=']:
        user_feedback = raw_input('Is the number higher (+), lower (-), or equal (=) to my guess?')

    # Use the User Feedback
    if user_feedback == '+':
        min_possible = guess + 1 # B/c low end is inclusive
    elif user_feedback == '-':
        max_possible = guess - 1 # B/c high end is inclusive
    else:
        print 'I knew the answer was ' + str(guess)
        break
```

Comment: random.randint() is actually inclusive at both ends... woops